# iOS: Changing the height of the main view

Tags: ios, user-interface

How would you change the height of the main view so that its height does not go beyond the tabbed navigation bar? I want the main view to be above the tabbed navigation bar.

Comment: Which classes contentview are you trying to manipulate?

Comment: Quick side-note : you're not supposed to put tags in your questions titles. ;)

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate the the main one - the one that shows up in every view.

Comment: Do you mean __below__ the tabbed nav bar? IE: You dont want the content to go underneath the navbar?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the content to not show up behind the navigation bar. If this is correct you can **uncheck** the **Under Top Bars** in your view controller.

[image]

You can try [this](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/ios7-weve-got-a-problem/) with code

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

you may also need to add

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

The `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` should be all you need, however depending on your setup and what you are doing with the navigation bar you may need the additional code above.

You can add those into your `viewDidLoad` or into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

If that doesn't work you can try something like [this](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2013/09/developing-for-ios-7-and-supporting-ios-6/) if you need to support ios 6 as well.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                     self.topOfViewOffset,
                                     self.view.frame.size.width,
                                     self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: I can't find these settings. By the way, I am not using storyboard.

Comment: @Julia are you using a view controller? EDIT: I have edited by answer

Comment: Yep I am using a view controller.

Comment: I have a method that looks like this: `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if( [viewController isKindOfClass: [UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: NO];
    }
}` Would I put that code in there?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a content view that has a width as wide as your ViewController, that has an origin point of 0,0 (it's top left corner starts at the very top left hand corner of the view) and that has a navigation controller directly below it, I would do something like this in my ViewDidLoad method:

```
yourcontentview.frame = CGRectMake(0, //x co-ordinate 
                                   0, //y co-ordinate
                                   self.view.frame.width, //set width as wide as the view's
                                   self.view.frame.height - yournavigationbar.frame.height); //take the height of the nav controller away from the view and see what space is left.
```

or alternatively if your nav controller is NOT at the very bottom of your view change:

```
self.view.frame.height - yournavigationbar.frame.heigh
```

to

```
self.view.frame.heigh - yournavigationbar.frame.origin.y
```

The above ^ gets the start location of the nav controller in the view (so if it starts at 500 points down, then the height of the contentview will not go past 500 points)

Hope they work!

also if there is lots of content, you can always stick it in a scrollview :)